# Open gallery in the camera directory

Tags: android, camera, gallery

In my Android project, I would like to open the gallery with a specific directory (DCIM/Camera path), Camera directory to be clear.

Is that posible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Try this:

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivity(galleryIntent);
```